# Thinking Sphinx showing excerpts of a many-to-many (or one-to-many) association

Tags: thinking-sphinx

I have:

```
define_index do
    .
    .
    indexes tags.name, :as => tags
end
```

How do I show the excerpts for tags? Doing search_obj.excerpts.tags does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excerpts method just calls back to the original object - so you'll need a method on it that returns all the tag data. Something like the following in the model:

```
def tag_names
  tags.collect(&:name).join(' ')
end
```

And then excerpts calls for that should be:

```
search_obj.excerpts.tag_names
```